# How to get data from pickle files into a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, twitter, pickle

I'm working on a social media sentiment analysis for a class.  I have gotten all of the tweets about the Kentucky Derby for a 2 month period saved into pkl files.

My question is: how do I get all of these pickle dump files loaded into a dataframe?

Here is my code:

```
import sklearn as sk
import pandas as pd
import  got3

def daterange(start_date, end_date):
for n in range(int ((end_date - start_date).days)):
    yield start_date + timedelta(n)

start_date = date(2016, 3, 31)
end_date = date(2016, 6, 1)

dates = []

for single_date in daterange(start_date, end_date):
    dates.append(single_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))

for i in range(len(dates)-1): 
    this_date = dates[i]
    tomorrow_date = dates[i+1]
    print("Getting tweets for " + tomorrow_date)
    tweetCriteria = got3.manager.TweetCriteria()
    tweetCriteria.setQuerySearch("Kentucky Derby")
    tweetCriteria.setQuerySearch("KYDerby")
    tweetCriteria.setSince(this_date)
    tweetCriteria.setUntil(tomorrow_date)
    Kentucky_Derby_tweets = got3.manager.TweetManager.getTweets(tweetCriteria)
    pkl.dump(Kentucky_Derby_tweets, open(tomorrow_date + ".pkl", "wb"))
```

Comment: You can load each into a list, append each list into a master list, then use the list to put it into a `DataFrame`

Answer (score 11):

You can use

1. `pd.read_pickle(filename)`
2. add it to a list
3. then `pd.concat(thelist)`

Answer (score 0):

this site can be help you :

- [pandas document](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_pickle.html)
- [ask python](https://www.askpython.com/python-modules/pandas/read-pickle-files-in-pandas)
- [geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dataframe-read_pickle-method-in-pandas/)

---

```
pd.read_pickle('tomorrow_date.pkl')
```

or

```
pd.read_pickle('tomorrow_date.pickle')
```

you should notice to last line it not be this `open(tomorrow_date + ".pkl", "wb")` it should be like this `open('tomorrow_date' + ".pkl", "wb")`
hop help you